# Bug in StackOverflow.com? Not showing 15 results

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

In stackoverflow.com, when I go to questions, it doesn't show the default 15 results, it shows a different number of results going from 5 to 10 usually. I have tried it with Chrome and Firefox.

In meta.stackoverflow.com it works correctly.

Does this happen to anyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the Hide Ignored Tags option on your preferences page?

I remember reading in an answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/large-blank-gap-between-question-list-and-pager) that it is applied on the client side so even though the database will return all the results fewer will displayed.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I was used to them being simply "desemphatized", and haven't realized that there weren't ignrored tag questions any more.