# Paging on search screen seems broken

Tags: support, status-bydesign, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug in StackOverflow.com? Not showing 15 results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/bug-in-stackoverflow-com-not-showing-15-results)

There seems to be an issue when paging search results. I often get an arbitrary number of results per page, even if the number is set to 30. <strike>I'm not sure how I can reproduce it in general, but</strike> it seems persistent right now when I search for `t-sql identity`:

[image]

The problem appears with Firefox 5.0 on Windows 7. It also appears on Google Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer

Neither browser has the problem, when I'm *not* logged in.

Here is an extract of the HTML code:

[image]

It looks as if the "Ignored" tags are filtered out from the search results on the client side using JavaScript only *after* paging has been applied on the server side.

**UPDATE**:

Another screenshot to support my case, I'm ignoring all tags on the first page (i.e. ignoring sql-server) :-)

[image]

Comment: Does it happen on other tabs, like "newest"?

Comment: Yes, on all tabs. It's not as extreme as on "relevance", though. Right now, I get 4 "relevance" on page 2, 17 "newest" on page 1, 20 "votes" on page 1, 13 "active" on page 1. It's really arbitrary... I'll add some more facts to the description

Comment: it isn't doing it for me; is there any change you have any client-script local to your machine, for example to hard-remove anything with ignored tags?

Comment: or easier: if you "view source", are they there? i.e. did we deliver them to your browser?

Comment: Yes, the answers are there, but invisible. See the updated question with the new screenshot. From the CSS classes it looks as if the "not interesting" tags will remove them in Javascript... But I'd think they should be remove on the server side, not on the client side, at least when there is paging available

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. When I remove some "ignored" tags, then the results re-appear...

Comment: You have the "hide ignored tags" option enabled, so it isn't hugely surprising that they are hidden. The question of whether we should apply that at the server is more interesting; not least, with the current UI you can actively add/remove ignored (etc) tags live, and it will update. It has been suggested that this is status-by-design...?

Comment: I think it is very surprising. I don't know many applications that page first and then filter. Usually filtering (and sorting) is always applied before paging... If you want your design to ignore that usability "law", that's fine with me, now that I know it :)

Comment: This is intentional: *all* of the question listing pages behave this way, it's consistent with the rest of the system...ignored and favorites are almost totally client-side functionality.

Comment: OK, I understand this was meant to work like that by design. It's also a good thing on *some* screens, because adding/removing favourite/ignored tags is quite fast. And this is highly applicable for the home-page, where there is no paging and the server load is probably a lot less if filtering doesn't have to be calculated on the server for every user. But don't you think paging through pages with alternatively 1/3/2/6/4 records is a bit weird? In extreme cases, you might even have 0 records on 5 consecutive pages...

Comment: @Nick: Does that mean that, if a page is served with 30 items, none of which match the client-side filters, that an empty page will be displayed?

Comment: @Robert, check out my added screenshot