# Possible bug with 'hide ignored tags' preference option?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Large blank gap between question list and pager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/large-blank-gap-between-question-list-and-pager)

I think I might be facing a possible bug in the stackoverflow question list  when browsing with Safari 4.0.2 under MacOS X.

If I select the 'Hide ignored tags' preference, then no question belonging to my ignored tags show up in the list (good), but there is a blank space proportional to the number of not shown questions in the bottom part of the list.

When opening the same question list under firefox (3.0.11 under MacOS X) the same questions show in the page, but there is no extra space between the last question shown and the 'Go to page' / 'Select number of questions per page' tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with WebKit. The same happens for Google Chrome on Windows.

Comment: It alse happens on Google Chrome running on Linux.

Comment: Webkit... is chrome and safari on **all** operating systems.

Comment: fixed in Chrome 5.0. Still an issue in Safari 4.