# Is this an issue on adding preferred tags and ignored tags?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, ignored-tags

I've gone through some questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8120/the-same-tag-can-be-in-both-interesting-tags-and-ignored-tags-list-they-should) ,[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94025/adding-feature-in-ignored-interesting-tags) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8679/possible-bug-with-hide-ignored-tags-preference-option) about adding preferred tags and ignored tags.

But, I saw another strange thing while adding tags to those list.
We can add tags which were not in the tags list ie, for ex, 'is','was'...

It should show an alert message that "This tag is not in the tags list." while adding those tags.

Is this an issue or it's not, that it won't affect any resources in the server

There is a chance for the user to mis-spell the tag and his/her preferred tag won't be highlighted, then this might get solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system doesn't care. It's not worth the time and resources for the system to sit there and check every single tag users attempt to enter. It lets you enter whatever you want because it's *simpler*. If the tag really does exist, questions under that tag will get highlighted. If it doesn't, *nothing happens*.

So, this is by-design simply because it doesn't affect anything. Besides, you have to be able to enter tags that don't exist in order to use wildcards `*` in tag names. You'll notice also that you can [enter the same tag as both a favorite *and* ignored tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161220/why-can-i-both-favorite-and-ignore-the-same-same-tag), as well as entering tags that exceed the maximum length.

Comment: this won't affect anything in server side, but for the user side, he should get informed that his preferred tag is in the site or not, is it?

Comment: @Azik: The only way to check that is to make a call to the server, and as stated, that's just not worth the server's resources. It doesn't affect anything server-side, so it's really not important at all. You can always check if a tag exists *yourself*.