# Hiding questions with Interesting and Ignored tags?

Tags: support, questions

I have "Hide ignored tags" turned on in my preferences. If a question comes along with an Interesting tag and an Ignored tag, what happens to it?

Comment: The universe collapses in on itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the hide ignored tags turned **off** they will display as both interesting and ignored.

If you have the hide ignored tags turned **on** it will hide it no matter how many interesting tags are in there as well.

Comment: You got a downvote.  Is your answer incorrect?

Comment: Nope. Likely because I posted a tad too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Its hidden..

What happens is Javascript hides or fades all questions with a `.tagged-ignored' class, and highlights all questions with a`.tagged-interesting` class. When a question has both classes, they overlap.

This is also why you will notice that when you hide ignored questions, you will have less questions on the entire page. Hiding the questions is taken over by javascript, not the server, so the server doesn't know to list more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right place to feedback on this, but I find the "hide"/"ignore" feature detracts from the overall high quality of the site:

Because it's done browser-side, users see the ignored questions flashing up briefly and then the list of questions collapses in on itself, leaving huge amounts of empty space at the bottom of the page, with a variable number of remaining questions shown that doesn't agree with the number the user chose to prefer. So: A waste of some bandwidth and a hit to the aesthetics and consistency.

Not that it's a big priority, but I feel that at some point the "ignore" filtering should be moved to server side.

Comment: Bring down the server or burn bandwidth, what will Jeff do to solve a browser issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/large-blank-gap-between-question-list-and-pager

Comment: Chrome 5.0 was just released and finally fixes this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to have an option to "Hide questions with ignored tags that do not have interesting tags".  That was my initial assumption about how the ignore feature would work.