# Question not showing in Interesting if they have a Fav and Ignored tag

Tags: discussion, tag-watching, ignored-tags, interesting-page

So, I came across this, and I think it might be bugged or should work the other way around.

Imagine I have in my Ignored tags [android](/questions/tagged/android), but I have in my Favorite tags [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite). If a question has both tags it is not being shown in my "Interesting Questions" tab.

I also have, "hide ignored tag" unchecked in my prefs.

Is this by design? Shouldn't Favorite tags have precedence over Ignored ones with that unchecked (as [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/hiding-questions-with-interesting-and-ignored-tags/15769#15769) suggests)?

Comment: If I'm ignoring a tag, I don't want to see any questions about that tag regardless.  I like the opposite precedence (favorite > ignored).

Comment: That is fine, what is the usefulness of that checkbox in the prefs then?

Comment: The checkbox you are referring to would hide any question using one or more of the tags you are set as ignored tags; when you have any ignored tags, but that checkbox is not selected, then the questions using those tags would be shown with a "ghost" effect.

Comment: @kiamlaluno this is not happening with me on the interesting page

Comment: I should have made that clear: I am referring to the front page and the questions listed under "questions." I don't see any "interesting questions" tab and I cannot comment for that page.

Comment: @kiamlaluno click the SO logo, see if interesting opens up for you