# The "Unanswered" page contains lots of useless space

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Large blank gap between question list and pager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/large-blank-gap-between-question-list-and-pager)

I have no clue about HTML and everything related, but I guess this is not what it is meant to be (ie a bug), so I'll try and describe.

When opening the "Unanswered Questions" page on SO, I see some questions on the left and the usual sidebar on the right. Scrolling down, I've got multiple pages of nothing but space, then finally the footer. I think this space should not be there. It is about the same for each of `my tags`, `newest`, and `votes`.

Just a shot in the blue, but could this be related to having many ignored tags?

I do not experience this on the usual "Questions" page, so I wondered why it is only on the Unanswered page.

Comment: This is a dupe, but I can't find it.  *I fail at this game.*

Comment: oh... well... I could not find it as well

Comment: note that this is specific to Chrome/WebKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have the "Hide ignored tags" option set in your preferences, the questions matching your ignored tags will be removed from the page completely (instead of greyed out).

If all of the questions on the page match with your ignored tags, then the whole page will be empty.

Also, the pagination controls (1 2 3 4 5 .. Next) always appear at the bottom of the page.

Comment: (edited question)