# 1.5-screen distance between question list and pager

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, ignored-tags, tag-watching

**Description**

I was very confused by the 1.5-screen distance between the bottom line of the list of unanswered questions and the pages-switcher (pager). This is caused due to very long list of unanswered tags (30), list of favorite tags (50) and ignored tags (50 elements). If I not see the pager then I will not go to the next page and therefore I **will not continue the search**.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. go https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered
2. scroll down to the end of question list
3. if your tag list is long enough then you should not see a pager (!)

**Environment**

My web browsers are Opera 11 and Firefox 3.6

"Hide Ignored Tags" feature is turned on.

**Screenshot**

You can see a gap depending on the number of tags.
[image: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/]

**Proposal**

Move pager up to the question list.
[image: proposal]

Comment: Do you have "Hide ignored tags" turned on?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, turned on

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large blank gap between question list and pager](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/large-blank-gap-between-question-list-and-pager)

Comment: @Pollyanna - Why not to simply add page switcher to the end of questions list instead of the end of tags list?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the problem a bit better.  This may not be a dupe of 2063.  Unfortunately I do not see the problem with my setup.  Can you submit a screenshot?

Comment: @Pollyanna - My question is **different** from "Large blank gap between question list and pager". The reason of my problem is a **long tags list**. The reason of the problem you mentioned is in the client-side rendering!

Comment: @Pollyanna - screenshot has been loaded.

Comment: Reproducible on Firefox 3.6

Comment: I guess this is related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75834/147423

Comment: @Pollyanna - Why not to move "15 30 50 per page" element "left" to the pager and "up" to the bottom of questions list?

Comment: @developer I don't think that would look good.  Maybe make a mockup to demonstrate your suggestion?

Comment: @Pollyanna - loaded my proposal screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is completed. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: done]

The right column height does not pull the pager down, as you suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a good solution would be to truncate the interesting tags list with a "and 324 others..." linking to the user's page where they can see all their interesting tags.

Comment: An expand/collapse solution would be faster and easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to truncate tags and put a link in the end `expand` and `collapse`. It would keep the controls where they are and would show only the top tags. And if the user wants to view more he could just open his list.